# How to create pop-up progress bar in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have tried

```
 <progress percent="dynamicObject" class="progress-striped active"></progress>
```

but, i need model pop up progress bar dynamically in Angularjs

Comment: use angular strap or bootstrap modal and make the href go to the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Angular modal progress bar](https://github.com/500tech/angular-modal-progress-bar), and examples on [their blog](http://blog.500tech.com/angular-modal-progress-bar/).

Answer (score -1):

Check out Angular-UI bootstrap.  Has a modal and a progress bar that could be combined.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I agree that solution sucks, instead of a simple start(), updatePercent(50) and done() methods you have to handle everything yourself form creating a modal to centering it, to preventing other actions, etc, its like trying to program is assembly - possible but like reinventing the wheel - really a waste of time